# Highcharts copy HTML of chart can't disable cursor change

Tags: html, highcharts, cursor, copy

I have a fairly complex collection of 4 highcharts. At one point I copy one chart's entire HTML to another DIV. Problem is on that copy if you mouse over the graph lines the cursor still changes to a hand (does not show tool tip or any other features). I've tried making the entire new DIV's cursor = "cursor:default;" and a few other things, but the graph lines still show the hand cursor not the pointer. When I try to create a simple version in JSFiddle the cursor never changes to a hand so I can't duplicate the problem. I want a copy of the chart with zero functionality of the chart.

The way I am copying the highchart to the new div is:

```
$('#copyTo').html($('#container').html());
```

Where "copyTo" is my new DIV and "container" is the original highchart

You can see a simplified fiddle here where I copy the highchart to the new DIV, but since the fiddle does not show the tooltip mousover as a hand in the original it does not in the copy either. http://jsfiddle.net/rplace/dZ7Wa/

How can I copy the entire highchart to a new DIV and have it act like a "picture" and not retain any of the functionality of the graph? Currently none of the rest of the chart's features works in the copy except the mouseover turns to a hand.

Thanks!

Comment: Actually if you view my fiddle you can see my problem in the "series" legend at the bottom. In my copy at the bottom, if you mouse over the series the cursor changes to a hand but does not "work" to toggle the series. I'd like the copy to by just a copy with no mouse events. On my site both the legend series and the graph lines show a hand when moused over. I want nothing to happen on the copy.

Comment: Try the code below I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks you SOOOOOOOOOOOOO much. I have been battling this on and off for days will I worked on more pressing matters. I wish I could do more then up vote you and mark as accepted. Good things happen of Friday the 13th!

Comment: Hehe take care Rich :) I was glad to help. Seems IE is rather nasty when using these selectors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code ( http://jsfiddle.net/6WS2A/ )

```
function copyClick(){
  $('#copyTo').html($('#container').html());
  var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
  var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ");
  if (msie > 0)   // IE detected , tested it on IE 10  
     $('#copyTo *[style*="cursor: pointer"]').css('cursor','default');
  else 
     $('#copyTo *[style*="cursor:pointer"]').css('cursor','default'); 
}
```

Comment: Not working for me. In your fiddle or on my end. If you put you mouse over the original highcharts legend where it has the blue dot and says "Series 1" you will see the cursor go form default (arrow) to pointer (hand). Clicking it will toggle the graph above on/off. If you then copy it to the new DIV. You still get the cursor change hovering over "Series 1" but no effect when clicking.

Comment: Weird. When I place my mouse over the 'Series 1' the mouse hand is no more after copying, I thought you wanted to achive that? I'm using Chrome btw.